# Disable checkboxes after fx. 5 checked boxes

Tags: javascript

I tried to, what this script: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/checkboxlimit.shtml is to do, but i have an issue since i post my checkboxes to a PHP array

This is the code I'm using for the form:

```
<?php 
$badges = get_user_badges($UserID, true, false);

$html='';
foreach ($badges as $Badge) {
    list($ID, $BadgeID, $Tooltip, $Name, $Image, $Auto, $Type, $Row,, $Show) = $Badge;
    if($Show == '1') $selected = ' checked'; else $selected = '';
    $html .= '<label><input id="showBadge" name="showBadge['. $ID .']" type="checkbox"'. $selected .'> <img src="'.STATIC_SERVER.'common/badges/'.$Image.'" title="'.$Name.'. '.$Tooltip.'" alt="'.$Name.'" /></label>  ';
}
echo $html;
?>
```

Using jQuery is *NOT* an option due to conflicting scripts

Comment: You would need to use javascript/jquery for this as you want to control the number of click events.

Comment: javascript is no problem, but as soon as i include the jQuery libary one of the global page functions break.

Comment: Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily in jquery, but since you want it specifically in javascript, please see my answer below :

In PHP :

```
$html .= '<label><input id="showBadge" onclick="counter(this)" name="showBadge['. $ID .']" type="checkbox"'. $selected .'> <img src="'.STATIC_SERVER.'common/badges/'.$Image.'" title="'.$Name.'. '.$Tooltip.'" alt="'.$Name.'" /></label>  ';
```

In JS :

```
var count = 0;
function counter(element){
   if(count<5){
       //do something
   }else{
     element.checked = !element.checked; 
   }
   count++;
   alert(count);
}
```

**Fiddle** : http://jsbin.com/OyIMebis/1

**Update : To include the total number of checkboxes with checked status**

```
var count = 0;

function counter(element) {
    if (count < 5) {
        //do something
    } else {
        element.checked = !element.checked;
    }
    count++;

    var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        totalCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
        if (inputElems[i].type === "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked === true) {
            totalCount++;
        }
    }
    alert("Total Checkbox = "+totalCount);
}
```

**Fiddle** : http://jsbin.com/OyIMebis/2/

**Update 2 :**

Simply replace

```
var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

with

```
var inputElems = document.getElementsByClassName("testing")
```

and you can select checkboxes with that specific class.

**Fiddle** : http://jsbin.com/OyIMebis/4/
Cheers

Comment: I find it to work, almost as expected, is there a way to make it count onces that are allready ticked?

Comment: Should proberly have said this earlier, but forgot. Very sorry about that. The form itself is very long, and other sections of the form has checkboxes too...

Comment: @PeaceDealer : lol.. gimme some time.., ill update the answer

Comment: I found the answer myself, by replacing getElementsByTagName with ClassName. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @PeaceDealer : Great.. ive updated it anyway for other users who may stumble upon this question..:).. cheers..

Answer (score 0):

try this code: add a class for each check box.

```
$html .= '<label><input class="chk_bx" id="showBadge" name="showBadge['. $ID .']" type="checkbox"'. $selected .'> <img src="'.STATIC_SERVER.'common/badges/'.$Image.'" title="'.$Name.'. '.$Tooltip.'" alt="'.$Name.'" /></label>  ';
```

In js:

```
$(".chk_bx").live("click",function(){
if($('.chk_bx:checked').length == 5)
{
   $(".chk_bx:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true);
}
else
{
  $(".chk_bx:not(:checked)").removeAttr("disabled");
}

});
```

Comment: Do you want to do in php or javascript?

Comment: i need them to be disabled with javascript after 5 random checkboxes are selected.

Comment: My console displays this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'click'

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Comment: Fixed and tested in my system. It's working fine. Please check. A comma was missing between `"click",function()`. Silly mistake :)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'live'. As i mentioned, jQuery does not seem to co-operate with my site...

Comment: Ok. no problem, however you found solution for your question.